# Smooth splashscreen transition in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I use `react-native-splashscreen` for my react-native android app. Splashscreen display as it is. 
At the same time i need `react-native-restart` to restart app on language changes.

`react-native-restart`will not display splashscreen.
So it will display an empty blank screen for 1-2 seconds on restart (on high end devices)

Now I resolve it via setting windowBackground as follow to imitate the launch screen.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ... 
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/launch_screen_bg</item>
    ...
</style>
```

But then another issue comes, during the transition of keyboard is being displayed, the windowBackground is shown. This is not a problem on mid-high performance device, but in low performance device it is very clear that the windowBackground is flickering and being shown (about 0.5 seconds of keyboard transition which is visible to human eye)

================================ 
Maybe i am using wrong method of doing it.

Because in low end device i have to set `android:windowBackground` or else it still have 3-5 seconds of white screen after splash screen before component render for first time.
OF course i can resolve it with setTimeout() here but this is `hackish` and will not work for `react-native-restart` as well

```
componentDidMount() {
    ...
    Splashscreen.hide()
}
```

So to summarise: 
1) I have a low end device, which will result in clear white screen after splashscreen load finish and before app js loads.
2) Setting a background image in resolving this will causes keyboard display transition displaying the splashscreen (which should not be the case, background should be transparent here)
3) `react-native restart` also will results in white screen for few seconds before app loads (which i think this only can be resolved with `android:windowBackground`. As i tried to set background in App.js it is not working.

So how to get a smooth splashscreen transition in such a cases? Am i using a wrong approach from the start?

Rules:
`android:windowSoftInputMode` must be `adjustResize`

Comment: Did you try calling SplashScreen.show() before the restart method?